# Cannot search package in PyPI with pip

Tags: python, pip, pypi

[nose-printlog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-printlog) is listed in PyPI but when I search the package by pip, I cannot see it by `pip search nose-printlog`.

Does anyone know why it's not searchable in pip?

Note: Now you can find it by the `pip search nose-printlog` command. This question was posted relatively in a short time after the package was uploaded.

Comment: The package is pretty new ... maybe `--no-cache-dir` will help

Comment: Also notice I'm able to search the package but only by full name (pip seems to not be a fan of `-` ..)

Comment: Thank you @cyrbil. I can search the package too (without --no-cache-dir option). I assume that it takes some delay to become available in pip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that is a heavy issue that persists since 2015, [here](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/326) there is the bug discussion group. 
03/04/2016 is still not resolved.


UPDATE: [Issue #397](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/397) has been raised for the same reason.

Comment: Thanks Lessio and I marked this as the accepted answer.
[Issue #326](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issues/326/some-packages-not-showing-up-when), which is mentioned in this answer, is currently resolved state and [Issue #397](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issues/397/my-package-doesnt-appear-in-the-search) has just been raised for the same (as of Apr 9th, 2016).

Answer (score 0):

Now I can search using the same `pip search nose-printlog` command.
Probably I needed to wait for several hours for it to be available in pip command.

Note that I didn't search the package 3 hours later from the registration on PyPI.

```
12:44 pm UTC - Registered to PyPI
 3:54 pm UTC - Still not searchable
 4:09 pm UTC - Searchable
```