# My uploaded package is not searchable in pypi, neither in pypi web UI nor PIP3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setup.py, pypi

I created a package, named [furigana](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=furigana&version=0.0.7) . This package page can be browsed by a user not logined to pypi. However, if I type "furigana" in the homepage of [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), it can not find my package "furigana".
I also used `pip3 search` to search it, and it also find nothing.

I ran below commands to create archive and upload it by twine:

```
python3 setup.py test
python3 setup.py sdist
twine upload dist/furigana-0.0.7.tar.gz
```

The output message of twine is:

```
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading furigana-0.0.7.tar.gz
```

My ~/.pypirc is

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
username:<my_username>
password:<my_password>
```

My setup.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup
from os import path

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

# Get the long description from the relevant file
with open(path.join(here, 'README.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    long_description = f.read()

setup(name='furigana',
        version='0.0.7',
        description='''convert Kanji in Japanese into Kanji attached with Hiragana (Furigana(振り仮名))
        For example, "澱んだ街角" => "澱(よど)んだ街角(まちかど)" ''',
        long_description = long_description,
        author='Miki.Liu',
        author_email='mikimotoh@gmail.com',
        url='https://github.com/MikimotoH/furigana',
        packages=['furigana'],
        classifiers=[
            # How mature is this project? Common values are
            #   3 - Alpha
            #   4 - Beta
            #   5 - Production/Stable
            'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
            'Environment :: Console',
            'Intended Audience :: Developers',
            'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
            'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
            'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
            'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
            'Topic :: Text Processing :: Linguistic',
            ],
        keywords='Japanese Language Processing',
        )
```

[Cannot search package in PyPI with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36385043/524781)  doesn't resolve my problem, the bitbucket repository is already removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot search package in PyPI with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31679944/cannot-search-package-in-pypi-with-pip)

Comment: I think you simply need to wait more while PyPI — quite an overloaded **free** service — index your newly uploaded packages.

Comment: I have updated the issue links in the linked duplicate question.